# Generating random routes with probability using randomTrips script

Tags: python-3.x, probability, reinforcement-learning, sumo

I want to generate a route.xml file using randomTrips. My network is very simple, 4 nodes (0,1,2,3) connected using 3 edges :  E0_1, E1_2 and E3_1. I have a principale route which is E0_1 E1_2 and I want this one to be generated with probability 1 and the other one with probability 0 (for example).

Here is my roucfg given to randomTrips script as an argument.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <routes>
        <route id="E01_E12" edges="E01 E12" probability="1" />
        <route id="E31_E12" edges="E31 E12" probability="0" />
    </routes>
    <flows value="5"/>
    <begin value="0"/>
    <end value="1"/>
    <o value="baselineRoute.rou.xml"/>
    <n value="baselineNet.net.xml"/>    
</configuration>
```

**My route file is weird. I have both routes generated.**

```
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://sumo.dlr.de/xsd/routes_file.xsd">
    <trip id="0.0" depart="0.00" from="E31" to="E12"/>
    <trip id="1.0" depart="0.00" from="E01" to="E12"/>
    <trip id="2.0" depart="0.00" from="E31" to="E12"/>
    <trip id="3.0" depart="0.00" from="E31" to="E12"/>
    <trip id="4.0" depart="0.00" from="E01" to="E12"/>
</routes>
```

This means that probability attribute dosn't work correctly.

Is there any way to fix it ? I also tried by giving it explicitly using the number attribute for each route. 5 for the principale one and 0 for the other one, but I still have the same output.
Any ideas ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

There may be a fundamental misunderstanding about what randomTrips is supposed to do. The function of the script is to choose random origins and destinations. If you already have your routes there is no need to use the script. You can just write your route file directly.

```
<routes>
    <route id="E01_E12" edges="E01 E12" />
    <flow id="flow1" route="E01_E12" begin="0" end="100" number="5" />
</routes>
```